# Add custom text under order details on WooCommerce My account view order pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, endpoint, account

I need to add some custom text under the Order Details section of the WooCommerce view-order page.

My goal here is to add some additional instructions:

> To cancel your license within the 30 day trial period click REFUND MY ENTIRE ORDER

How might I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following to display a custom text in "View Order" pages:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', 'action_order_details_after_order_table', 10, 4 );
function action_order_details_after_order_table( $order, $sent_to_admin = '', $plain_text = '', $email = '' ) {
    // Only on "My Account" > "Order View"
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'view-order' ) ) {
        printf( '<p class="custom-text">' .
        __("To cancel your license within the 30 day trial period click on %s" ,"woocommerce"),
        '<strong>"' .__("Refund my entire order", "woocommerce") . '"</strong>.</p>' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.